# Using Trace in Prolog

Tags: prolog, trace

How could I use the predicate `trace` in Prolog without tracking all the predicates being called from external modules? I am aware of the predicate `trace/2` but I am under the impression that this can only trace or ignore one predicate at the time. Am I wrong? Is there any other way to trace the predicates being called solely from my file more efficiently?

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: External modules or builtin predicates?

Comment: @CommuSoft builtin predicates are already ignored as far as I am aware and therefore I want to ignore external modules.

Comment: Do you know you can tap 's' to skip a predicate?

Comment: @SharanDuggirala: Please put an effort and look into existing answers, before asking such questions.